# Can call a WCF service via $http but not ngResource

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, angularjs

Currently, I am learning AngularJS. But I have now lost a couple of hours with this issue.

I try to call a WCF service from AngularJS via ngResource. I was able to get it working with $http, but not via ngResource.

The service is quite simple:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "flowers", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<BaseFlower> GetFlowers();



public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public List<BaseFlower> GetFlowers()
    {
        var flowers = new List<BaseFlower>();

        flowers.Add(new BaseFlower { Name = "Rose", Price = 1, BoughtOn = DateTime.Now });
        flowers.Add(new BaseFlower { Name = "Lilly", Price = 2, BoughtOn = DateTime.Now });
        flowers.Add(new BaseFlower { Name = "Heliconder", Price = 3, BoughtOn = DateTime.Now });

        return flowers;
    }
```

Following some examples I tried to call the WCF service but had no luck, here is the AngularJs code:

```
var ngFlower = angular.module("ngFlower", ['ngResource']);

ngFlower.factory("Flower", function ($resource) {
    return {
        flowerData: $resource('http://localhost:61585/Service1.svc/flowers')
    }
});

ngFlower.controller("flowerCtrl", function ($scope, Flower) {
    $scope.items = Flower.flowerData.query({});
    DB = $scope.items;
});
```

Since I switched from $http to "resource", the WCF service cannot be reached anymore.

Comment: The call to resource is async. Does the call not happen (see in browser tools) or does $scope.items do not get filled?

Comment: just checked, I get 
"Failed to load resource".

Comment: Is it possible to see the reason a bit more in detail? Anyway, I think i'll go for a self hosted WebApiController, hopefully it will solve the problems.

Comment: IF this is a server error, try to make the request using $http and $resouce and see the difference in the request payload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your problem is that $resource usage expects a rest api backend.  Your web service is expecting a POST request and you're sending a GET request with query method.

Look into using an `ApiController` class

Comment: That is not the case i think, as the method declared if you see has a `WebGet` attribute set.